# How to get specific a -> b <- c node ordering with graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I have the following graphviz diagram:

```
digraph {
    {
        rank = same;
        g -> p;
        g -> c;
        c -> p;
    }
    subgraph global {
        g -> ga -> g;
    } 
    subgraph command {
        c -> ca -> c;
    }
}
```

It generates close to what I want:

[output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45jKc.png)

but I'd like for the `p` node to be in the middle of the `g` and `c` nodes. How do I get graphviz to comply?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [neato](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/neato/) as the layout: `graph [layout = neato]`.

```
digraph {
    graph [layout = neato]
    {
        rank = same;
        g -> p;
        g -> c;
        c -> p;
    }
    subgraph global {
        g -> ga -> g;
    } 
    subgraph command {
        c -> ca -> c;
    }
}
```

[image: NeatO version]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using **dot**.
It uses **dir=back** ("backwards edges" see https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/dir/) and **constraint=false** (see https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/constraint/)

```
digraph {
    {
        rank = same;
        g -> p;
        g -> c [constraint=false]
        p -> c [dir=back]
    }
    subgraph global {
        g -> ga -> g;
    } 
    subgraph command {
        c -> ca -> c;
    }
}
```

Giving:
[image]